# Java .jar files to run on double-click

Tags: windows-7, java, file-association, jar

How can I configure .jar files run on double-click in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `regedit.exe`
search for : `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command`

Probably, you have in the value:`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`
change it to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

(make sure that the path points to your actual `java.exe`, for it depends on the java version you have installed)

Good luck. It worked for me. ;-)

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to use javaw. java.exe is ok for me. But the whole command was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for configuring the file assocations you'll need can be found here:

jar : Java Glossary - Making Jar Files Double Clickable
  http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jar.html#ASSOCIATION

Comment: Buy a tool for this? You must be kidding.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to make a shortcut to the jar file and edit it to open **"java -jar path/to/file.jar"**. It's the only workaround I have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 64 you might also find the 32bit registry key:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jar_auto_file\shell\open\command

This key might be set to 32bit values ( "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" or alike) creating conflict with 64 bit version thus the issue, so adjust it to this value:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*

You should be good to go with double-clicking executable jar files without conflict, now.

Cheers

Bob Qwack